# cant update Excel file if Excel is not open?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, excel, ms-office

I am trying to Read and Update Excel using Oledb and Dataset in C#.

Read Operation work fine even for both Excel file is open or not.

Update Operation work only if file is Open
but **Update Operation giving error if Excel file is not Open**

```
Code :
string query2 = "SELECT * FROM [Fixtures Input$A:IP]";
        string qupdate;        
        string conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("SAE.xls") + ";Mode=ReadWrite;" + "Extended 
Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=0;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
        con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        con.Open();
        cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(query2, con);
        adap2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd2);
        ds2 = new DataSet();
        adap2.Fill(ds2, "Fixtures Input");

        #region "DoingRowEmpty"
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow aaa = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[i];
            aaa.BeginEdit();
            //aaa.ItemArray[2] = "test";
            aaa.EndEdit();
            id = Convert.ToString(i);

            qupdate = "UPDATE [Fixtures Input$] SET [Fixtures] = '', [Fixture Type] = '', [x] = '' , [(R/N)] = '' , [Fixture Quantity] = '' ,"
                      + " [Quantity of Gangs] = '' , [Sensor mount] = '' , [new lamps] = '', [High bay] = '', [burn/year] = '' ,[Ladder] = ''  where [id] = '" + id + "'";

            adap2.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(qupdate, con);

            adap2.Update(ds2.Tables[0]);
}
#endregion
```

**any suggestions plz ?**

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: error : Data type mismatch in criteria expression.                   but if I will open Excel and run, the project will execute successfully

Answer (score 0):

is it necessary Excel file should be open before run program ?